# simplify python beautifulsoup find_all expression

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have this python code with bs4 and request packages:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://dolarhoy.com/"
page = requests.get(url)  # Carga contenido HTML de la URL pasada como parámetro
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

values = soup.find_all('div', class_="values")
compra = values[0].find_all('div', class_="compra")
val = compra[0].find_all('div', class_="val")

print(val)
```

And the section of website I'm trying to scrape:

```
<div class="values">
    <div class="compra">
        <div class="label">Compra</div>
        <div class="val">$181</div>
    </div>
    <div class="venta">
        <div class="label">Venta</div>
        <div class="val">$184</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to print `[<div class="val">$181</div>]`, I did it but with 2 lines of code:

```
compra = values[0].find_all('div', class_="compra")
val = compra[0].find_all('div', class_="val")
```

There is a way to simplify that with only one line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can *directly* find the class `val` on the `soup` instead of creating a separate variable to search for it.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


url = "https://dolarhoy.com/"

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")
print(soup.find("div", class_="val").text)
```

Output:

```
$181
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `select` instead of `find_all`. `select('div.compra.val')`

like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
divs = soup.select('div.compra.val')
print(divs)
```